# How to remove all elements matching a specific criteria from a list of lists?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse a list of strings contained into columns of a pandas Dataframe and extract some date of birth (dd.dd.dddd or dd/dd/dddd format). My aim is to store it in a new list called date and keep the same index as in my previous dataframe. Here is my first sample code:

```
date=[]
for i in range(df['Text']):
    a=re.findall(r'[\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{4}', df['Text'][i])
    date.append(a)
```

However, if I only write this code (which parses the good values but without enough restriction) I would obtain date of birth but also some other date less relevant:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['17/02/1997'], ['26.07.1990', '17.03.2014', 
'01.11.2017', '01.07.2013', '06.09.2013', '01.10.2011', '01.06.2013', 
'25.09.2013', '15.03.2014', '15.09.2011', '15.08.2014', '11.09.2009', 
'02.07.2011', '15.09.2008', '30.07.2009', '15.09.2007', '30.07.2008'], [], 
[], [], []]
```

Therefore, I know for fact that every date after 2003 is not a date of birth. 
So I would like a script that would only return:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['17/02/1997'], ['26.07.1990'], [], 
[], [], []]
```

I then write this script but it seems that my loop is missing some date to check if it complies with the criteria (see the print to check the one the loop is focusing on):

```
date=[]
for i in range(df['Text']):
    a=re.findall(r'[\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{4}', df['Text'][i])
    for k in a:
        print(k +"prems")
        if k[-4:].isdigit()==True and int(k[-4:])>2003:
            print(k)
            a.remove(k)
    date.append(a)


[Out]:
17/02/1997prems
26.07.1990prems
17.03.2014prems
17.03.2014
01.07.2013prems
01.07.2013
01.10.2011prems
01.10.2011
25.09.2013prems
25.09.2013
15.09.2011prems
15.09.2011
11.09.2009prems
11.09.2009
15.09.2008prems
15.09.2008
15.09.2007prems
15.09.2007
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['17/02/1997'], ['26.07.1990', '01.11.2017', 
'06.09.2013', '01.06.2013', '15.03.2014', '15.08.2014', '02.07.2011', 
'30.07.2009', '30.07.2008'], [], [], [], []]
```

Does anyone understand why some date that are after 2003 are not removed from the list based on this criteria considering they answer the criteria of the loop ??

If there would be a simpler way in the regex expression (I am a beginner in that field) that would be possibly be best as well.

---

EDIT 
Thanks to @Sunitha comments I have my desired output doing that:

```
date=[]
for i in range(df['Text']):
    a=re.findall(r'[\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{4}', df['Text'][i])
    date.append(a)

#Capture the non birthdate
not_date=[]
for i in range(df['Text']):
    a=re.findall(r'[\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{4}', df['Text'][i])
    for k in a:
        print(k +"prems")
        if k[-4:].isdigit()==True and int(k[-4:])>2003:
            print(k)
            not_date.append(k)

#Remove the non birthdate from the list of list
for k in not_date:
    print(k)
    for i in range(len(date)):
        if k in date[i]:
            date[i].remove(k)
print(date)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Removing elements from a list while iterating over that list always causes me problems.  Have you thought about building a new list from the old one?

Comment: Do you mean create len(date) number of lists with the values inside date and then apply the criteria on all these new lists ?

Comment: If you provide a sample of your input list and corresponding desired output list it will make things much clearer.

Comment: I created a new simple list with all the date values I got from the first code but I have the same result, the criteria seemed to be checked in 1 date out of 2...

Answer (score 3):

As Ben Jones has pointed out in the comments `Removing elements from a list while iterating over that list always causes problems`. So instead of removing elements from the list `a`, append the result directly to the list `date`

```
date=[]
for i in range(df['Text']):
    a=re.findall(r'[\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{1,2}[/\.][\d]{4}', df['Text'][i])
    for k in a:
        print(k +"prems")
        if k[-4:].isdigit()==True and int(k[-4:])>2003:
            print(k)
            date.append(k)
```

Comment: Thanks :). It has allowed to capture all the date that were not the birthdate into one list. However, that is not my desired output, I still need to remove all these values from my more complex list

Comment: Even though your answer is sufficient and honestly a more proper approach; you can always create a separate list of objects to remove, then remove them once you've determined all objects that need to be removed.